# How to import ES Module into UI5 controller

Tags: javascript, sapui5, ui5-tooling

Given an ES Module `dictionaryAPI.mjs`:

```js
export const DICTIONARY_API = Object.freeze({
    someKey: "someValue"
});
```

I want to import it to my UI5 controller. As far, as I understand, UI5 doesn't support `.mjs` extensions, therefore I've changed an extension from `.mjs` to `.js`. Then, I try to add it into the UI5 controller, precisely, to the utility controller `ControllerUtilities.js`:

```js
sap.ui.define([
    "com/myApp/dictionaryAPI"
    ],
    (dictionaryAPI) => ({…}));
```

When I run the app, I get an error:

```js
'com/myApp/controller/ControllerUtilities.js': Unexpected token 'export'

sap-ui-core.js:53 Uncaught (in promise) ModuleError: Failed to resolve dependencies of 'com/myApp/controller/Login.controller.js'
 -> 'com/myApp/controller/BaseController.js'
  -> 'com/myApp/controller/ControllerUtilities.js': Unexpected token 'export'
    at p1 (https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js:53:213)
    at j1.failWith (https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js:40:43)
    at https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js:65:1556
Caused by: SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
```

It looks like, UI5 doesn't recognize the [`export`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) statemen from the ES Module.

Is there any option to import ES Module into UI5 controller?

Used version: OpenUI5 1.96.0

Comment: Not just like that, but you can look into using the official UI5 typescript support, which does allow for import and export statements https://github.com/SAP/ui5-typescript

Answer (score 6, accepted):

UI5 uses by default UMD import syntax (`sap.ui.define`, `sap.ui.require`). To make it understand other module types you have to 'trick' it into thinking that the module is UMD.

This can be accomplished by using the [ui5 cli](https://sap.github.io/ui5-tooling/pages/CLI/).

You have to build a proper folder structure (package.json, ui5.yaml, webapp folder) and in the ui5.yaml file you can define [project shims](https://sap.github.io/ui5-tooling/pages/extensibility/ProjectShims/) for the corresponding ES modules.

A cheap and hacky alternative would be to include the ES modules trough
`<script src="path/to/module" type="module">` tags but I don't know anyone who would reccomend this because this doesn't allow bundling.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to create a new module as [fmi21](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13163112/fmi21) mentioned.

Your API could look like this which is returning just an object with the `DICTIONARY_API`. So you are also able to add more properties to the API.

```js
sap.ui.define([], function () {
"use strict";

    return {
        DICTIONARY_API : Object.freeze({
            someKey: "someValue"
        })
    }
});
```

Then you can import it like you already do in your `ControllerUtilities.js`

You also have the possibility to load your JSON file directly into the model via the `manifest.json`

```
{
  "sap.ui5": {
    "models": {
      "YOURMODELNAME": {
        "type": "sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel",
        "uri": "PATH TO JSON"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case it is a model, which needs to be accessible system-wide, the easiest way would be to declare it in `manifest.json` under `sap.ui5`/`models`:

```json
"dictionaryAPI": {
    "type": "sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel",
    "uri": "model/dictionaries/api.json"
},
```

Alternatively, it's possible to load a model from the controller of the root view (`rootView` in `manifest.json`), which makes the model available for every view during the entire app run:

```js
async loadDictionaryData(dataSource, modelName) {

    const dictionaryModel = new JSONModel();

    await dictionaryModel.loadData(dataSource);

    this.getView().setModel(dictionaryModel, modelName);

}
```

No need to care about data sync/async loading, reuse, ESM/UMD, etc.